# Mac hangs after Snow Leopard installation

Tags: macbook-pro, install, snow-leopard

I have a white 2007 MacBook, 2.16 GHz, 3GB RAM.
 It was happily running OS X.6.1 for a while but a friend borrowed it and left a lot of rubbish on it, so thought I'd reinstall Snow Leopard and then up to Lion again. Tried OS X.5.1, X.6, & X.6.3, all Apple original DVDs.

After they say "Installed successfully", when I must input info: name, address, postcode, phone No., where will the computer be used?, job description etc.  click is held continuously  and I get the spinning ball and the machine hangs. Any ideas?

Comment: When the Computer says "Successfully installed", then I must input info, name , address, Postcode, phone Nr. etc. where will the computer be used?, Job description. It says this info will help Apple serve you better. Click continus and get spinning ball. I assume the computer is talking to Apple.

Comment: I also have a white MacBook 1.83ghz., Core Duo. I was also working fine until I tried to instal OS 10.4.9(the set of grey disks that came with the computer. Installs Ok, Give loads of info in, click Continue..........spinning ball. So it's not the computers and our wifi is working fine.

Comment: @Seanog That info is optional (if memory serves). What happens if you try to avoid it?

Comment: "When the computer says "successfully installed"....... this applys to both Mac books, the 2.16ghz and the 1,83ghz. They were working fine until I tried to reinstall the OS.

Comment: benwiggy- on the older OS you MUST give all the info, On OS X.6 you only give a name, but you must give something in.

Comment: Tried booting from an external drive but the computer won't recognise any of the DVDs.

Comment: Ok, took the HD & SSD and connected them to my iMac , they tested Ok, no faults. Reinstalled drives and have now got to the stage where everything looks Ok until you try and do something. Open Safari and it loads Apple's latest offering & then promptly locks up.
I saw a 2007 2.16 selling as scrap on ebay but the seller assured me that the OS worked Ok. It just arrived.......and guess what. Yes it loads just like the other 2 then locks up.
Going nuts.